# How can I block the creation of multiple accounts on one device in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I create applications, but the problem is that the user can create multiple accounts on one device, which spoils the whole purpose of the application. How can I make the application check data from firestore and compare it with the current ones?

```
private void storeUserData(String name, String email, String password) {

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.edtemail.getText().toString(),binding.edtpassword.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                String referCode = email.substring(0,email.lastIndexOf("@"));
                String Deviceid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                UserModel model = new UserModel(name,email,password,
                        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cashapp-278ce.appspot.com/o/plac.png?alt=media&token=61f99d71-5ada-47f0-b72a-9b69e4e32471",
                        referCode,
                        Deviceid,
                        "false",
                        5,
                        5,
                        5);
                String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();

                firestore.collection("Users").document(id).set(model).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1K76.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Do you need to search for a particular email in Firebase before signing in?

Comment: before creating an account or logging in, check whether the database contains an available Android ID created earlier when creating an account for the first time, if yes, then block further account creation or logging at specific device

Comment: This is not possible to enforce.  The user is free to uninstall or clear the application's data and start over like they've done nothing with it before.  There is also no way to reliably uniquely identify a modern Android device.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for [blocking functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=1st). There is a `beforeCreate` function that can help you run and use some logic even before the user is created. So you can perform any logic you want, even search in a Firestore database for the existence of an Android ID.

Comment: Hey Jakub. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?